# How do I get a returned value first with async tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am trying to learn how async and await works and I am having difficulties with it. What I understand from async await is that, when we have an async function and we await it, we can get the result returned from the async function immediately after its finished using the await syntax.

We can also allow the program to move to the next line in the code without waiting for the code to complete, which in return allow us to save time for user facing programs.

It will be useful in applications such as database calling where we can "ignore" the database call as sometimes it can be expensive and move on to the next few line of codes, and when the results are returned from the database, we can then do something with it.

So, I have made a practice with it using BANK queues as an example.

Scenario: BANK1 and BANK2 have different queue numbers, and if my number from either bank gets called first, it will print {BANK} QUEUE CALLED.

Although the output is showing that queue time is being run concurrently, it is not giving me the desired output of what I am expecting. For example, if BANK2 gets called first followed by BANK1, BANK1's output will still be printed out first followed by BANK2.

Code:

```
import asyncio
import random

async def bank1():

    countdown = random.randint(0,10)
    print("bank1 queue time is: ", countdown)

    for i in reversed(range(countdown)):
        print("bank1: " + str(i) + ' waiting in queue')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return True

async def bank2():
    countdown = random.randint(0,10)
    print("bank2 queue time is: ", countdown)

    for i in reversed(range(countdown)):
        print("bank2: " + str(i) + ' waiting in queue')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return True

async def main():
    bank1_queue = asyncio.create_task(bank1())
    bank2_queue = asyncio.create_task(bank2())


    await bank1_queue
    if bank1_queue:
        print("BANK1 QUEUE CALLED")

    await bank2_queue
    if bank2_queue:
        print("BANK2 QUEUE CALLED")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Advices and criticism are greatly appreciated as I am eager to learn!